# Как сохранить пропорции добавив margins css?

Tags: html, css

Ниже будет представлен сделанный мною код. Должно получиться как на этой картинке: [image: Как должно быть]

и вот что выходит у меня(`margins` еще нет):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дизайн, цвет и границы не имеют значения. Первая проблема в том, что при добавлении `margins` каждому `div` 3 колонка уходит вниз(что конечно логично). Но мне нужно сохранить пропорции(в данном случае 33% на каждую колонку). Как это сделать добавив `margins`? 
И вторая проблема. Если присмотреться к моему варианту, то можно заметить, что расстояние от крайней левой колонки больше чем расстояние от крайней правой колонки. Как это изменить?
Вот мой код:

```css
body{

 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}


* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
h1{
text-align: center;
margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.row{
 width: 100%;
}
.col-lg-4, .col-md-6, .col-sm-12{
 position: relative;
 background-color: gray;
 padding:20px 10px 0px 10px;
}
p{
 margin: 10px;
}
span{
 position: absolute;
 right:0;
 top:0;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 border: 1px solid black;
 padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
#Chicken{
 background-color: pink;
}
#Beef{
 background-color: red;
}
#Sushi{
 background-color: yellow;
}


/*for large devices*/

@media(min-width: 992px){

 .col-lg-1,.col-lg-2,.col-lg-3,.col-lg-4,.col-lg-5,.col-lg-6,.col-lg-7,.col-lg-8,.col-lg-9,.col-lg-10,.col-lg-11,.col-lg-12
{
 float:left;
 border:1px solid black;
}
.col-lg-1 {
 width:8.33%;
}
.col-lg-2 {
 width:16.66%;
}
.col-lg-3 {
 width:25%;
}
.col-lg-4 {
 width:33%;
}
.col-lg-5 {
 width:41.66%;
}
.col-lg-6 {
 width:50%;
}
.col-lg-7 {
 width:58.33%;
}
.col-lg-8 {
 width:66.66%;
}
.col-lg-9 {
 width:74.99%;
}
.col-lg-10 {
 width:83.33%;
}
.col-lg-11 {
 width:91.66%;
}
.col-lg-12 {
 width:100%;
}
}

/*for medium devices*/
@media(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px){

 .col-md-1,.col-md-2,.col-md-3,.col-md-4,.col-md-5,.col-md-6,.col-md-7,.col-md-8,.col-md-9,.col-md-10,.col-md-11,.col-md-12
{
 float:left;
 border:1px solid black;
}
.col-md-1 {
 width:8.33%;
}
.col-md-2 {
 width:16.66%;
}
.col-md-3 {
 width:25%;
}
.col-md-4 {
 width:33%;
}
.col-md-5 {
 width:41.66%;
}
.col-md-6 {
 width:50%;
}
.col-md-7 {
 width:58.33%;
}
.col-md-8 {
 width:66.66%;
}
.col-md-9 {
 width:74.99%;
}
.col-md-10 {
 width:83.33%;
}
.col-md-11 {
 width:91.66%;
}
.col-md-12 {
 width:100%;
}
}
/*for small devices*/

@media(max-width: 767px){

 .col-sm-1,.col-sm-2,.col-sm-3,.col-sm-4,.col-sm-5,.col-sm-6,.col-sm-7,.col-sm-8,.col-sm-9,.col-sm-10,.col-sm-11,.col-sm-12
{
 float:left;
 border:1px solid black;
}
.col-sm-1 {
 width:8.33%;
}
.col-sm-2 {
 width:16.66%;
}
.col-sm-3 {
 width:25%;
}
.col-sm-4 {
 width:33%;
}
.col-sm-5 {
 width:41.66%;
}
.col-sm-6 {
 width:50%;
}
.col-sm-7 {
 width:58.33%;
}
.col-sm-8 {
 width:66.66%;
}
.col-sm-9 {
 width:74.99%;
}
.col-sm-10 {
 width:83.33%;
}
.col-sm-11 {
 width:91.66%;
}
.col-sm-12 {
 width:100%;
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Hello Coursera!</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>
<h1>Our Menu</h1>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 chi"><p><span id="Chicken">Chicken</span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p></div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 bee"><p><span id="Beef">Beef</span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p></div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 sus"><p><span id="Sushi">Sushi</span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p></div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: посмотрите как это в бутстрепе верстается. Нужно не маргин ставить, a padding для `col-*`. а серые блоки уже внутри контейнеров

Comment: Artem Gorlachev,  спасибо! Помог Ваш ответ.